# NavigateTo same page again does not refresh?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, navigation, refresh

I have 2 pages in my Windows Phone 8 XAML app, "**MainPage**" and "**Play**".
I NavigateTo **Play** from **MainPage**, then hit the back button to return to **MainPage**.
Once I NavigateTo **Play** again, 2 things happen that I find confusing:

1. My constructor for **Play** is called again, yet the controls on the page still contain data from the last page visit.
2. Even though I see data in page members the data does not render on the screen.

There's something basic here I'm missing? How do I either get a completely new page; or re-render the previous instance?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0):

You can use different class to hold your data, I think that is the problem. You can see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/600449/IntroductionplustoplusObjectplusOrientedplusProgra) for more info.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers my question, and surely the link you provided is silly.
My question concerns how Windows Phone handles creation/destruction of pages. Specifically, why am I seeing my constructor called yet my members are not re-initialized?